# Django app deployment digitalocean stuck at nginx home page

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, digital-ocean

I have followed the DigitalOcean tutorial to deploy a django app at DigitalOcean, the guide is:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps

**Question:**
The problem is that when I go to the IP with the browser, I see the *Welcome to nginx* page and not my django app.

**Tutorial important points**

Respect the tutorial, I have not seen the following error as tutorial says: `server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32`

Another important difference between what I did and tutorial is that `gunicorn_django --bind yourdomainorip.com:8001` did not work for me.

I use this statement to start gunicorn:

`web: gunicorn --chdir code/computationalMarketing computationalMarketing.wsgi --log-file -`

**My configuration**

At `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` I have symlink called `computationalMarketing` that refers to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/computationalMarketing`

This files has the following lines:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1;
    server_name 159.65.18.211;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

    root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/computationalMarketing/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

I have a virtualenv at `/opt/computationalMarketing` and inside this I have another `computationalMarketing` folder with the `Git` repo file.
This repo has the following structure:
[image]

My installations are:

```
sudo pip3 install numpy==1.13.3
sudo pip3 install pandas==0.22.0
sudo pip3 install scikit-learn==0.19.1
sudo pip3 install pymysql==0.8.1
sudo pip3 install psycopg2==2.7.3.2
sudo pip3 install django==2.0.5
sudo pip3 install django-connection-url==0.1.2
sudo pip3 install whitenoise==3.3.1
sudo pip3 install gunicorn==19.7.1
```

The database is a Postgresql, which I can connect without problem.

Can anyone guess why I am seeing the nginx page and not my django app?

Comment: This is nice guide: https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2017/01/deply-django-with-nginx.html

Answer (score 0):

You've told nginx to listen for this particular config on the localhost only. Don't do that. Remove that `listen` line altogether.

There are a few other weird things in your question. The command you claim to be using to start gunicorn is a Procfile instruction, it's not something you could actually run at the command line. What command are you *actually* using to start gunicorn? Whatever you use, you do need to tell it to serve on the same port that nginx is proxying to - in your case 8001.